# How Can I Read an Environment Variable in WSDL File?

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl

I have changable IP:Port addresses in my application and when one of them is changed, I have to compile and create a new jar. I decided to use these IP:Port addresses as environment variable, so whenever they are changed, changing the environment variables will be enough and I will not create a new jar.

How can I read an environment variable in WSDL file?

The code piece I need to read the environment in is:

```
<wsdl:service name="myService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:example" name="port1">
        <soap12:address location="EnvironmentVariableHere"></soap12:address>
    </wsdl:port
</wsdl:service>
```

The environment variables shape will be like this:

```
export MyVar=http://127.0.0.1:8090/webservices/MyWebPostService?wsdl
```

(Every time only IP:Port = 127.0.0.1:8090 is being changed)

Comment: You don't and shouldn't. Your endpoint exposing that WSDL should include the proper location. If you are using Spring WS that is already handled for you others like Apache CXF do as well.

Comment: I am using Apache CXF in a SpringBoot Project. What do you suggest for changable IP:Ports? I could not find another solution.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change a thing, the WSDL should be modified on the fly by Apache CXF already.

Comment: @M.Deinum  This wsdl file is inside of the project under the Resources folder.  The code pieces I shared on question are in that file, not in an outsource wsdl, because of that IP:Port changes must be on project side. I will not change the outsource wsdl files, I will change only wsdls inside of the project.

Comment: @M.Deinum when I compile the project, autogenerated classes are being made by the insource wsdl file with using the given IP:Port.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The wsdl is that for a webservice client or are you building a webservice yourself?

Comment: I am building an post web service to post some data.

Comment: Then the generated wsdl from `url?wsdl` already automatically includes that information. Or at least it should, unless you are telling Apache CXF to statically export that WSDL. If it wouldn't it would mean for every environment you deploy in you would need to rebuild the application.

Comment: @M.Deinum so I understood that from your sentences: If I could change the IP:Port dinamically like I want to make, It would not effect the insource wsdl unless compiling again?

Comment: Last try. You don't need to change it, that is already being done by Apache CXF based on the server it runs on/URL that is being called. You don't need to change anything **unless** you are statically serving that WSDL instead of letting it being processed by Apache CXF.

Comment: @M.Deinum I see I dont need but I have to. To be clear, the services IP and Port info is defined in the insource wsdl in my project which I gave an example code on my question above. Sometimes, the target services IP address and Port is changed, and whenever it is changed my post service fails to send data to the target. The only thing I can do is changing the targets IP and Port in the code I gave above and compiling the project, after then my post services can send data. I dont want to make this everytime the IP:Port is changed.

Comment: @M.Deinum I decided to save the IP adres on /etc/hosts file in ubuntu and gave a name like TargetIP and when I write that instead of IP addres in the code it works properly and when ever I change the IP address from the /etc/hosts it works properly. But I cant define a Port information, so I need to recompile the project with updating the port info. I need to get the IP and Port info like in my question, because I have to, I dont want to make it willingly.